# textbox Datacontext a list index

Tags: wpf, datacontext

Is it possible to set a datacontext of a textbox to a particular index of a List>?

I have a list that I am using for a data context of a Chart and I have been able to access the data with code on textchanged with this:

```
        double d;
        if (!double.TryParse(point4.Text, out d))
        {
            d = 0;
        }
        ValueList.valueList[3] = new KeyValuePair<string, double>("4th", d);

        if (chart1 != null)
        {
            chart1.Refresh();
        }
```

But if possible I'd like to just use a data context.

Edit to add my current classes:

```
public class GraphItems
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public double Data { get; set; }

    public GraphItems(string K, double D)
    {
        Key = K;
        Data = D;
    }
}

public class GraphData : ObservableCollection<GraphItems>
{
    public GraphData()
    {
        Add(new GraphItems("1st", 0));
        Add(new GraphItems("2nd", 4));
        Add(new GraphItems("3rd", 3));
        Add(new GraphItems("4th", 2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can bind to an index of a List.  You just use the normal indexing syntax within the binding expression; for example:

```
<TextBox DataContext="{Binding MyList[3]}" />
```

Comment: alright, but here is another question, I am using a KeyValuePair, is there a way to bind to the value of the KeyValuePair?

Comment: @Herrozerro sure, you can bind to `Key` and `Value`, which are properties of `KeyValuePair`.

Comment: what would that look like?  I am using: {Binding ValueList.valueList[1]} to get the particular record.

Comment: I am looking to bind to just the value, as I am pretty much getting the key by using the index.

Comment: @Herrozerro then it should be `{Binding ValueList.valueList[1].Value}` -- however, note that for this to work, `ValueList` and `valueList` have to be properties, not variables.  And I guess you'd need an `ObservableCollection` if you need changes to propagate to the UI.

Comment: just a quick question, I changed some things around.  Made a class called Graph Data which is an observablecollection of a another class called graph items.  this works for chart but I am still having an issue with getting the binding of the Textbox.  I am using: DataContext="{Binding data[1].Data}", is this correct?  Should I instead be binding the Text property to this?

Comment: That's right if `data` is an ObservableCollection/List with items that contain a property `Data`.

Comment: I added my classes to the main question, I ditched the list and just went with two classes, should i keep the list?

Comment: It looks right -- the binding would be `data[1].Data` to get the double value ..?